# Boolean object randomly appearing in render

Tags: boolean-modifier

Very new to Blender.  Playing around with booleans.  Although an animated boolean is turned off it appears for a single frame in the render.  I'm digging around the forums to find the same issue but not finding anything.   [appears about 80% of the way through the render](https://www.dropbox.com/s/91d9vuyaeodvuu3/Glitch-Web.mov?dl=0)

Comment: I would check to make sure that it isn't keyframed for any reason. You can also try adding it to a separate collection and disabling that collection. Best option is always to apply the boolean modifier if you have no reason to change it in the future and then delete the boolean object. Based on your description it sounds like a glitch. I also always render out individual frames to pngs so that I can go in and easily re-render individual frames if needed. You might have already done this, but its a useful method rather than rendering directly to video.

Comment: Could you share your .blend file? Follow the instructions here  https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=wpawX8QL" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/wpawX8QL/)

Comment: Here's the project file.  Thanks for the replies!